# JOIN with GROUP BY and COUNT not displaying empty rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL server 2005. Two tables `CLASS` and `RESERVATION`. I would like to count the number of reservations for a class, but I get this bug where classes that are empty but have a reservation that was cancelled are no longer shown. I want all classes from the `CLASS` table to be displayed. The query:

```
SELECT C.ClassId AS Id, ISNULL(COUNT(R.ReservationId),0) As numberStudents
FROM CLASS AS C
LEFT JOIN RESERVATION AS R ON R.ClassId = C.ClassId
WHERE R.Cancelled = 0 OR R.ReservationId IS NULL
GROUP BY C.ClassId
```

I understand that the class isn't shown because there is indeed a reservation (`R.ReservationId` isn't `NULL`) but then `Cancelled` is 1, so neither condition in the where clause is true. I expected the `ISNULL` to catch those cases, but the rows are simply not displayed. I have tried using `DISTINCT` and grouping by `R.ClassId` but keep getting the following error:

`CLASS.ClassId is invalid in the select list. This column is not included in the GROUP BY clause or aggregate function.`

I think I see the logic error. It should be something like the following (and I know this contains syntax errors, please treat as pseudo-code).

```
SELECT ClassId, Count(Reservations having R.Cancelled = 0)
FROM CLASS LEFT JOIN RESERVATION
```

Do I need a nested query to achieve this? How can I do this?
Hope my question is clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all reservations to be shown, move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT C.ClassId AS Id, COUNT(R.ReservationId) As numberStudents
FROM CLASS C LEFT JOIN
     RESERVATION R ON
     ON R.ClassId = C.ClassId AND R.Cancelled = 0
GROUP BY C.ClassId;
```

`COUNT()` will return `0` if there are no matches.  There is no need for `ISNULL()` (or `COALESCE()`).

Comment: This works, but I have to wait another 5 minutes before I can select it as the answer. I like the answer's simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Do your pre-aggregate by class as a query from reservation and left-join to that... something like:

```
SELECT 
       C.ClassId AS Id,
       COALESCE( PreQuery.NumStudents,0) As numberStudents
   FROM 
      CLASS C
         LEFT JOIN 
            ( select R.ClassID, count(*) as NumStudents
                 from RESERVATION R 
                 where R.Cancelled = 0
                 group by R.ClassID ) PreQuery
            on C.ClassID = PreQuery.ClassID
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question! Better luck next time.

Comment: @James, thanks, but there is no luck to it... many solutions to problems.  What might be less effective in one place may offer an alternative in another :)